# Difference between Saas and off-premise in erp?

Tags: cloud, saas, erp

what is the difference between off-premise and Software as a service ? 
I understood that both means that the application runs on remote server farms. So why in ERP they are considered two different things ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

off premise is more to do with where the ERP is hosted while SaaS is to do with what is offered to you by the ERP. In other cases platform is offered as a service and in some cases infrastructure is offered as a service.